# Trying to find the general term for a recursive serie more easily

Tags: logic

I have a general expression which is the following:

$$b_{0} = 1$$

$$b_{n} = 5b_{n−1} + 12n - 11 \quad ∀n  \in \mathbb N^∗$$

And that I have to resolve in the easiest way possible. I know that I could use the generative function technique, but the exercise specify in bold to choose the easiest technique possible, which is probably not this one. I am pretty sure it is not a geometric or algebraic function, so 
I am confused. How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: regroup the terms and write the recurrence successively as:

- $b_n + 3n = 5 \left(b_{n-1} + 3(n-1)\right) + 4\;$, then:
- $b_n + 3n + 1 = 5 \left(b_{n-1} + 3(n-1) + 1\right)$

The latter means that $b_n + 3n + 1$ is a geometric progression.

Comment: I tried to understand but i'm really not sure i got it right... if I understand well, 
should i be finding the general term for
$$ b_{n} + 3n + 1$$ 
and then substract $$3n + 1$$ to it to find what I am looking for?

Comment: @Sophie.B Precisely. You get that $b_n+3n+1=c \cdot 5^n$ for some constant $c\,$, so $b_n = c \cdot 5^n - 3n -1\,$, then determine the constant from the initial condition.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! Can I justify the C i found (2 if I am not wrong) only by saying that i found it by trial and error with the first term?

Comment: @Sophie.B Glad you worked it out. `found it by trial and error with the first term` That's not "*trial and error*", it's actually solving the equation given by the initial condition $b_0=1=c \cdot 5^0 - 3 \cdot 0 - 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose
$b_n
= ub_{n-1}+vn+w
$
and we want to find
$r, s$
such that
$b_n+rn+s$
forms a geometric progression.
Then we want
$b_n+rn+s$
to be a constant multiple of
$b_{n-1}+r(n-1)+s$.

(I'm trying to show that
there is no magic here.)

Then

$\begin{array}\\
b_n+rn+s
&=ub_{n-1}+vn+w+rn+s\\
&=ub_{n-1}+(v+r)n+w+s\\
&=ub_{n-1}+(v+r)(n-1)+v+r+w+s
\qquad\text{replace the } n \text{ by } n-1\\
&=u(b_{n-1}+\frac{v+r}{u}(n-1)+\frac{v+r+w+s}{u})\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
to make this match,
we must have
$r = \frac{v+r}{u}
$
and
$s = \frac{v+r+w+s}{u}
$.

Solving for $r$ and $s$,
from the first equality,
$ur = v+r$
so
$r(u-1) = v$
or
$r = \dfrac{v}{u-1}$.

From the second equality,
$us = v+r+w+s$
or
$s(u-1) = v+r+w
=v+w+\dfrac{v}{u-1}
$
so
$s = \dfrac{v+w}{u-1}+\dfrac{v}{(u-1)^2}
$.

For the example here,
$u, v, w
= 5, 12, -11
$
so
$r =\dfrac{12}{5-1}
=3
$
and
$s 
= \dfrac{12-11}{5-1}+\dfrac{12}{(5-1)^2}
= \dfrac14+\dfrac34
=1
$
(as used by dvix).

Therefore,
setting
$c_n = b_n+rn+s
$,
we have
$c_n = uc_{n-1}$
so that,
by induction,
$c_n = u^n c_0$
or,
since
$c_0
= b_0+s$,
$b_n+rn+s
=u^n(b_0+s)
$
or
$b_n
=u^n(b_0+s)-rn-s
$.

Note that
if $u=1$
then
$b_n-b_{n-1}
=vn+w
$,
so we can sum both sides
to get
$b_n-b_0
=\sum_{k=1}^n (b_k-b_{k-1})
=\sum_{k=1}^n (vk+w)
=v\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}+nw
$.